# forensic acquisition with SANS SIFT Workstation Appliance

Tags: computer-forensics

Is there a way to do a forensically sound acquisition of a USB drive or SD Card using the SANS SIFT workstation? That is, does it have a built-in write-blocker?

Comment: You can mount the drive read-only (this is true of Linux in general, depending on whether or not the distro tries auto-mounting drives). But a physical write-blocker is best practice in case the OS decides to mount it (especially true if you are only using SIFT as a VM and thus the host OS will try mounting the drive).

Comment: You can mount the drive read-only, but many Linux file systems will modify the file system on the media, even if you mount read-only. You really should use the loop-back device, and mount from the loopback. I guess I should write this up. Yes, a write blocker is best, but not always available.  If you use SIFT in VMWare you can tell VMWare to not let the host OS mount.

Comment: bingo: it sounds like you've answered your own question ;) -- only one small correction, you should refer to the device properly as the loop device, as loopback is a term reserved for networking devices. It's a common mistake, so don't feel bad, but for clarity's sake I must be pedantic on SO ;)

Comment: Thanks. Do you want to write up the answer?

Comment: Nahh, this is my "work" / disposable account, so I don't care much for rep ... but I'll gladly upvote your answer :)

Comment: And here I thought you were the singer/song writer.... Or is that Dylan Thomas?

Comment: "Do not go gentle into that good night...." :P

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful as to what the host operating system does when you attach a device to the computer. The "appliance" is a virtual machine, and the host operating system may touch the device before the appliance does.

Your best bet is to use a hardware write blocker.

By the term "SIFT appliance", I am assuming that you mean the Linux-based one. There is a Windows-based SIFT workstation that they give out in some of the forensics classes.

The Linux-based appliance does not automatically mount devices, so you can image the drive by using dc3dd and using the device itself (such as /dev/sdb) as the input to dc3dd. It won't alter anything.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me more about the Windows-based SIFT workstation? I have not encountered it. Yes, I was speaking of the Linux-machine. The Linux-based appliance *did* automatically mount the drive until I reconfigured it as described above.

Comment: The Windows 8.1 SIFT workstation is given when you take one of the SANS forensics courses, specifically with FOR 408 - Windows Forensics. They give you a license code for it. It is a VMWare virtual machine with a large number of tools pre-installed.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Thanks.